# Splitting out semicolon separated values with percentage in SQL into new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datatable in MS-SQL (using SQL Server 2014 Standard) with the following illustrative layout (and unfortunately have no ability to change):

```
ID   Score   Segmentation
 1 |  500  | GROUP 1 - SET A - 50%; GROUP 2 - 25%; GROUP 1 - SET G - 25%
 2 |  200  | GROUP 1 - SET B - 25%; GROUP 5 - SET A - SET B - 50%; GROUP 6 - 25%
```

Where I need to create a query with the following output:

```
---------------------------
Segmentation  | Total Score
---------------------------
GROUP 1       | 425
GROUP 2       | 125
GROUP 3       | 125
GROUP 5       | 100
GROUP 6       |  50
---------------------------
```

That is, the result set should display each unique group with a total summed score, built by the group's percentage of total in each row (i.e. Group 1 total score is 500*0.5 + 500*0.25 + 200*.25 = 425). Parameters on the data are;

- All groups in each row always add up to 100%
- There is not a static list of groups
- Groups may be listed more than once in each row
- New groups may be added during the course of use
- Groups may have multiple sets, but do not need to be considered in the result
- Group names may include spaces and the '&' character

I had previously found a solution posted at: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/ however it seems to break and does't like the '&' character.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another option using a CROSS APPLY.  I should note, that this split/parse is XML safe.

I don't see where GROUP 3 is coming from (perhaps a typo?)

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Score int,Segmentation varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1 ,  500  , 'GROUP 1 - SET A - 50%; GROUP 2 - 25%; GROUP 1 - SET G - 25%'),
(2 ,  200  , 'GROUP 1 - SET B - 25%; GROUP 5 - SET A - SET B - 50%; GROUP 6 - 25%')

Select B.Segmentation
      ,Total_Score    = sum((A.Score*B.Value)/100)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Segmentation = left(RetVal,charindex(' - ',RetVal))
                      ,Value        = cast(replace(reverse(left(reverse(RetVal),charindex(' - ',reverse(RetVal)))),'%','') as float)
                 From  (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Segmentation,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) C1
             ) B
 Group By B.Segmentation
```

Returns

```
Segmentation    Total_Score
GROUP 1         425
GROUP 2         125
GROUP 5         100
GROUP 6         50
```

Comment: Yes, Group 3 was a typo

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three ways to do this in SQL Server:

- A user-defined function.
- A recursive CTE.
- XML processing.

The specialized characters might affect XML processing, but they should be fine for the first two.

For instance:

```
with cte as (
      select id, score,
             left(segmentation, charindex(';', segmentation + ';') - 1) as segment,
             substring(segmentation, charindex(';', segmentation + ';') + 1, len(segmentation)) + ';' as rest
      from t
      union all
      select id, score,
             left(rest, charindex(';', rest + ';') - 1) as segment,
             substring(rest, charindex(';', rest) + 1, len(rest))
      from cte
      where rest like '%;'
     )
select left(segment, charindex(' - ', segment)) as segmentation,
       sum(score * cast(replace(right(segment, charindex(' ', reverse(segment, ' ')) - 1), '%', '') as float) / 100.0) as TotalScore
from cte
group by left(segment, charindex(' - ', segment));
```

This is doing a lot of weird string processing because the data structure is simply awful.  I would encourage you to work to fix the data structure so the data is more useful.

Comment: The recursive cte would fail, the cte does not have a column `segmentation`. It should be either `Segment` or `Rest`.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/24fef/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t(ID INT ,   Score INT ,   Segmentation VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO t VALUES
 (1 ,  500  , 'GROUP 1 - SET A - 50%; GROUP 2 - 25%; GROUP 1 - SET G - 25%'),
 (2 ,  200  , 'GROUP 1 - SET B - 25%; GROUP 5 - SET A - SET B - 50%; GROUP 6 - 25%')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Groups 
      ,SUM(CAST( Score * REPLACE(Percentage , '%','') /100.0 AS decimal(18,2))) Total_Score
FROM 

(
    SELECT  ID
           ,Score 
           ,LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))), 8) Groups
           ,RIGHT(RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))),4) Percentage
    FROM   
    (SELECT    ID
             , Score
             , Cast ('<X>' + Replace(Segmentation, ';', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
    FROM    t
    ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
) q
GROUP BY Groups
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/24fef/1/0)**:

```
|   Groups | Total_Score |
|----------|-------------|
| GROUP 1  |         425 |
| GROUP 2  |         125 |
| GROUP 5  |         100 |
| GROUP 6  |          50 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try following XML / XQuery based solution:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    ID INT, 
    Score INT, 
    Segmentation VARCHAR(1000)
)
INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES
 (1 ,  500  , 'GROUP 1 - SET A - 50%; GROUP 2 - 25%; GROUP 1 - SET G - 25%'),
 (2 ,  200  , 'GROUP 1 - SET B - 25%; GROUP 5 - SET A - SET B - 50%; GROUP 6 - 25%')

 SELECT t.GroupName, TotalScore = SUM((t.Score * t.GroupPercent) / 100.00)
 FROM (
     SELECT Score       = y.Score,
            GroupName   = LTRIM(z.XmlCol.value('(item/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')),
            GroupPercent= TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(5, 2), REPLACE(LTRIM(z.XmlCol.value('(item/text())[last()]', 'VARCHAR(100)')), '%', ''))
     FROM (
     SELECT *, SegmentationAsXML = CONVERT(XML, '<row><group><item>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(x.Segmentation, ';', '</item></group><group><item>'), '-', '</item><item>') + '</item></group></row>') 
     FROM   @Table1 x
     ) y
     OUTER APPLY y.SegmentationAsXML.nodes('row/group') z(XmlCol)
 ) t
 GROUP BY t.GroupName
```

Note #1: I assume that source strings (Segmentation doesn't include XML reserved chars).

If source strings contains XML reserved chars then you could test following function:

`REPLACE(x.Segmentation, ';',`

->

`REPLACE( (SELECT x.Segmentation AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')), '; '`

Note #2: It converts `Segmentation`(s) strings into XML thus:
`'GROUP 1 - SET A - 50%; GROUP 2 - 25%'` becomes
`'<row><group><item>GROUP 1</item><item>SET A</item><item>50%</item></group><group><item>GROUP 2</item><item>25%</item>'`

Note #3: It uses `last()` XQuery function in order to access last `item` within every `group`.